# Weblogic - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEMac$DES9797Alg3

Tags: java, security, weblogic-10.x

I am working with a Java Web application and I need to generate a MAC using 3DES algorithm. Code is working without problems on a Weblogic 10.3 but the problem came when I tried to run the application in a different Weblogic, similar version (10.3.1).

This is my code:

```
public String getMac(String inkey, String data) throws Exception {

    byte[] out = new byte[8];

    try {

        // if I commend this line, the result is the same
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        // this loop proves the BC provider is there
        for (Provider p : Security.getProviders()) {

            log.debug("--");
            log.debug(p.getName());
            log.debug(p.getInfo());
        }

        try {

            BouncyCastleProvider bc = new BouncyCastleProvider();

            // class is there, no problem
            log.debug("info" + bc.getInfo());

            DES9797Alg3 alg3 = new DES9797Alg3();

            // class is there, no problem
            log.debug("alg3" + alg3.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error BouncyCastleProvider classes");
        }

        log.debug("length: " + inkey.length());

        if (inkey.length() < 48)
            inkey += inkey.substring(0, 16);

        byte[] rawkey = hexStringToByteArray(inkey);
        DESedeKeySpec keyspec = new DESedeKeySpec(rawkey);
        SecretKeyFactory keyfactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
        SecretKey key = keyfactory.generateSecret(keyspec);

        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("ISO9797Alg3Mac");

        mac.init(key);

        mac.update(data.getBytes());

        mac.doFinal(out, 0);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        log.error("Error generating MAC X9_19", e);

        throw new Exception("Error generating MAC X9_19", e);

    }
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeKey
    at javax.crypto.Mac.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Mac.init(DashoA13*..)
    at es.indra.netplus.sec.services.util.UtilMac.getMac(UtilMac.java:180)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for Mac(provider: BC)cannot be found.
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1268)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1220)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEMac$DES9797Alg3
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:283)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:256)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:54)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:176)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:35)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1262)
```

I do no understand why error says that `org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEMac$DES9797Alg3` is not there. It is possible that 'java.security' is looking in another place? I have requested to the server administrator to copy the library in the endorsed directory, but not I am not sure if this is going to work and way this is happening.

Notice that even if I remove 'Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());' line, in the list of available providers, BC is listed.

This is the list of providers I got:

```
-- -- --
CSSX509CertificateFactoryProvider
CSS JDK CertPath provider
1.0
-- -- --
SUN
SUN (DSA key/parameter generation; DSA signing; SHA-1, MD5 digests; SecureRandom; X.509 certificates; JKS keystore; PKIX CertPathValidator; PKIX CertPathBuilder; LDAP, Collection CertStores, JavaPolicy Policy; JavaLoginConfig Configuration)
1.6
-- -- --
SunRsaSign
Sun RSA signature provider
1.5
-- -- --
SunJSSE
Sun JSSE provider(PKCS12, SunX509 key/trust factories, SSLv3, TLSv1)
1.6
-- -- --
SunJCE
SunJCE Provider (implements RSA, DES, Triple DES, AES, Blowfish, ARCFOUR, RC2, PBE, Diffie-Hellman, HMAC)
1.6
-- -- --
SunJGSS
Sun (Kerberos v5, SPNEGO)
1.0
-- -- --
SunSASL
Sun SASL provider(implements client mechanisms for: DIGEST-MD5, GSSAPI, EXTERNAL, PLAIN, CRAM-MD5; server mechanisms for: DIGEST-MD5, GSSAPI, CRAM-MD5)
1.5
-- -- --
XMLDSig
XMLDSig (DOM XMLSignatureFactory; DOM KeyInfoFactory)
1.0
-- -- --
SunPCSC
Sun PC/SC provider
1.6
-- -- --
WebLogicCertPathProvider
WebLogic CertPath Provider JDK CertPath provider
1.0
-- -- --
WLSJDKCertPathProvider
WebLogic JDK CertPath provider
1.0
-- -- --
BC
BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.46
1.46
```

BC is there, moreover, the same version I got inside my war file.

I have googled many hours with no luck, hope someone can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After spending many hours on google trying to fix the error doing change in the code, the problem was solved adding the library in the server domain lib directory. Anyway, I still do not understand why this happens.