# Bouncycastle XmlSignatureFactory NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: java, bouncycastle, xml-signature

I have a Problem with checking an XMLSignature using BouncyCastle for verifying Sigantures that use ECDSA.

Here are the relevant lines of code:

```
BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
Security.addProvider(provider);   
//some unrelated code
XMLSignatureFactory factory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM", provider);
```

At the last line, the following Exception in thrown:

```
javax.xml.crypto.NoSuchMechanismException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: DOM for provider SC
```

If I change the line to

```
XMLSignatureFactory factory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
```

I get

```
javax.xml.crypto.MarshalException: unsupported SignatureMethod algorithm: http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-ripemd160
```

Anyone got any Ideas what causes this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first error, you can read in the error description that "no such algorithm: DOM for provider SC". That is weird, because it says "provider SC" (Sun PC/SC provider) and not "provider BC" (BouncyCastle Security Provider) as it should. It looks like you code (internally) is not using Bouncycastle as you want. You should find out why this is happening. It could be something regarding BC library and classpath (if you are working with an application server) or the providers order configuration.

Second error. You change your approach getting XMLSignatureFactory. This one is better, because if you do not specify the provider, because:

> This method uses the standard JCA provider lookup mechanism to locate
>   and instantiate an XMLSignatureFactory implementation of the desired
>   mechanism type. It traverses the list of registered security
>   Providers, starting with the most preferred Provider. A new
>   XMLSignatureFactory object from the first Provider that supports the
>   specified mechanism is returned.

But now, algorithm is not there. so, why? Here, I would say that BC is not being used. It is there? Review your classpath.

It may help to list all provider available:

```
for (Provider p : Security.getProviders()) {

    log.debug(p.getName());
    log.debug(p.getInfo());
}
```

Comment: BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.46 is listed when i list all providers

Comment: just saw that the complete entry is: "name: SC" "info: BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.46", so SC is the BouncyCastleprovider.

Comment: You sure? Take a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10817964/980472 When I listed providers BouncyCastle name was "BC".

Comment: i can only tell you what i see, the log says SC = BouncyCastle Security Provider^^

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I can't tell from the answer or comments. The thing is that Bouncy Castle doesn't provide a service for XmlSignatureFactory, AFAIC.

Answer (score 1):

guess from your second exception, since you want to validate the xml signature,
you may have use some code like the following, code from https://www.massapi.com/class/xm/XMLSignatureFactory-2.html

```
// Step 1: Load an XMLSignatureFactory instance. This factory class will
// be responsible for constructing almost all the major objects we need
// in working with XML Signature in JSR-105 APIs, except those related
// to KeyInfo.
XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

// Step 3 : Find all Xml Signature element into the provided XML
// document (here for sample use only the first)
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "Signature");
if (nl.getLength() == 0) {
    throw new Exception("Cannot find Signature element!");
}

// Step 4: Create a DOMValidateContext instance (extract public key from
// the "KeyInfo" bloc using overrided KeySelector impl.)
DOMValidateContext valContext = new DOMValidateContext(new KeyValueKeySelector(), nl.item(0));

// Step 5: Unmarshal the Signature node into an XMLSiganture object.
XMLSignature signature = fac.unmarshalXMLSignature(valContext);

// Step 6 : Validate signature
boolean isValid = signature.validate(valContext);
if (isValid) {
    System.out.println("OK");
}
```

but the xml representation has something like

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>  
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>  
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-ripemd160"/>  
            <Reference URI="">  
                <Transforms>  
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>  
                </Transforms>  
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>  
                <DigestValue>bHS+6uf8KbJV4AGzoHNHLfnXvKM=</DigestValue>  
            </Reference>  
    </SignedInfo>
    ...
</Signature>
```

therefore, factory failed to unmarshall the xml representation to XMLSignature object.
actually `fac` was provided by the `org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI` Provider, check `$JRE_HOME/lib/security/java.security` for sure. `fac` is an instance of `DOMXMLSignatureFactory` class.
the unmarshall actions will try form `Signature` object, and must form child object first, such as `CanonicalizationMethod` and then `SignatureMethod`, so at last reach the invocation that raise exception,
at `DOMSignedInfo` constructor `DOMSignedInfo(Element var1, XMLCryptoContext var2, Provider var3) throws MarshalException`

```
Element var5 = DOMUtils.getNextSiblingElement(var4, "SignatureMethod");
this.signatureMethod = DOMSignatureMethod.unmarshal(var5);
```

just one more step to `DOMSignatureMethod.unmarshal` static method, it use `http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-ripemd160` to look up Digital Signature Algorithm,
but `DOMSignatureMethod` only support the following algorithm,

```
rsa-sha1
rsa-sha256
rsa-sha384
rsa-sha512
dsa-sha1
dsa-sha256
hmac-sha1
hmac-sha256
hmac-sha384
hmac-sha512
ecdsa-sha1
ecdsa-sha256
ecdsa-sha384
ecdsa-sha512
```

and the solution:
add BC provider to Security and use **XMLSignature from org.apache.santuario -xmlsec** project to verify,

```
public boolean verify(String signedXML) throws Exception {
    Document doc = null;
    try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(signedXML.getBytes(Charset.forName("utf-8")))) {
        doc = MyXMLUtils.read(is, false);
    }

    XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();
    xpath.setNamespaceContext(new DSNamespaceContext());

    String expression = "//ds:Signature[1]";
    Element sigElement =
            (Element) xpath.evaluate(expression, doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

    XMLSignature signature = new XMLSignature(sigElement, "");
    KeyInfo ki = signature.getKeyInfo();

    if (ki == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No keyinfo");
    }
    PublicKey pk = signature.getKeyInfo().getPublicKey();

    if (pk == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No public key");
    }

    return signature.checkSignatureValue(pk);
}
```

more demos from repo: https://github.com/Honwhy/xml-sec